# Keep button focused when using mulitple button groups

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to create multiple `btn-group`, where each group is isolated from other.

My intention is keeping the focus when clicking on a button from a group and not stealing its focus when clicking on another group.

For instance:

```html
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Isolate Button group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Right</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Another Isolate Group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Upper</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Center</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Bottom</button>
</div>
```

When I click on `Upper` button, it's selected and keep focused, but if next I click on `Left` button, the `Upper` lost its focus. I would like to keep its focus instead.

Is there a custom button group class or an attribute which can keep the focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Bootstrap Radio Toggle Buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#radio-toggle-buttons)

Even with JavaScript I believe that behavior is impossible. `focus` events can only occur on one element at a time. What I gather is you want a single button per group to be *selected*. That behavior is called toggling which can of course be done through any group of elements using JavaScript.

`<button>`s by themselves do not behave like this without JavaScript. In Bootstrap, JavaScript it is responsible for certain class combinations and elements to behave in ways they normally can't.

In order to meet your criterion, you can use `<label>`s and `<input type='radio'>`.

1. `<input>` is placed before a `<label>`

   ```
   <input> <label></label>
   ```
2. Add `class='btn-check'`, a unique `#id`, a `name` of a group to the `<input>`, and `type='radio'`

   ```
   <input id='b1' class='btn-chk' name='grp1' type='radio'>
   ```
3. Add `class='btn'`, `[for]` with the value of the `<input>`'s `#id`

   ```
   <label class='btn' for='b1'>TEXT</label>
   ```
4. Repeat #1 thru #3 insuring that each `#id` is unique and each `[for]` matches.
5. Wrap everything in a `<div>`, `<section>`, etc. and assign `class='btn-grp` to it.

   ```
   <div class='btn-group'>
     <!-- All of the <input>s that share the same `name` 
          and the associated <label>s 
     -->
   </div>
   ```
6. Repeat #1 thru #4 ensuring that each `name` for each `<input>` match *within* their own `.btn-grp` and is different than any `name` *not within* that particular `.btn-grp`.

   ```
   <div class='btn-grp'>
     <input name='grp1' ...>
     <input name='grp1' ...>
     <input name='grp1' ...>
   </div>

   <div class='btn-grp'>
     <input name='grp2' ...>
     <input name='grp2' ...>
     <input name='grp2' ...>
   </div>
   ```

With this setup it isn't focus it's a property or an attribute called `checked`. In CSS it can be referenced with the pseudo-class `SELECTOR:checked` and in JavaScript `NODE.checked` as a property and  as an attribute `NODE.toggleAttribute('checked')` or in HTML `<TAGNAME checked>`.

***Note:** in the demo below toggling behavior is actually HTML. No JavaScript was loaded, only Bootstrap stylesheet was used.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Radio Button Groups</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container">
    <section class='col'>
      <section class='row'>

        <div class="btn-group mt-5 mb-2" role="group" aria-label="Primary Button Group">

          <input id='p1' type='radio' class="btn-check" name='primary'>
          <label class="btn btn-primary" for='p1'>Left</label>

          <input id='p2' type='radio' class="btn-check" name='primary'>
          <label class="btn btn-primary" for='p2'>Middle</label>

          <input id='p3' type='radio' class="btn-check" name='primary'>
          <label class="btn btn-primary" for='p3'>Right</label>

        </div>
      </section>

      <section class='row'>

        <div class="btn-group mt-2" role="group" aria-label="Secondary Button Group">

          <input id='s1' type='radio' class="btn-check" name='secondary'>
          <label class="btn btn-secondary" for='s1'>Upper</label>

          <input id='s2' type='radio' class="btn-check" name='secondary'>
          <label class="btn btn-secondary" for='s2'>Center</label>

          <input id='s3' type='radio' class="btn-check" name='secondary'>
          <label class="btn btn-secondary" for='s3'>Bottom</label>

        </div>

      </section>
    </section>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So I don't have option, I'll need to used input instead of button. Thank you for your detailed explanation!

Comment: You're very welcome. What exactly were you going to do with `focus`? Chances are what want to do is just as easy using `checked`, or if you want a plethora of specialized events and behaviors wrap everything in a `<form>` .

Comment: No because of focus, the highlight after clicking a button. I would like to keep that highlight after clicking, just like radio button with checked state, but for regular buttons, because I already have the cascade configured for button. With inputs I'll need to update the css, but no big deal.

Comment: That's good. Just keep these CSS in mind: `SESLECTOR:checked > SELECTOR {NEW STYLES}` `:checked` pseudo-class and `>` Adjacent Sibling Combinator

Comment: For a detailed explanation of `<input>` and `<label>`s see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44771168/2813224)